# liquibase-core update method does not create databasechangeloglock table

Tags: java, database, database-migration, liquibase

I am updating the version of `liquibase-core` dependency in Java (now 4.21.0) and notice that the `update()` method is deprecated. Instead, I should use an update method with two arguments: `Contexts`, and `Writer`.

The old, deprecated `update` method used to create two tables before doing anything else: an `databasechangeloglock` and `databasechangelog` table. When I use the new, non-deprecated signature of the `update` method, this no longer happens and no `databasechangeloglock` is generated. Consequentially, running from scratch generates an error because the required table does not exist.

I tried to do some debugging and noticed that `generateSql` from `CreateDatabaseChangeLogLockTableGenerator` is no longer invoked, while this is the case for the deprecated versions of the `update` method.

Could anyone explain how I could fix this issue and still generate the required tables?

Error logs:

[image]

Seems like there's an open issue on this: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/4150

Answer (score 4):

It seems that following change introduced the the deprecated update methods: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/3866/files#diff-68544baf236f867c4abf85787c970ddf1aee4802dd2ffb663ea5be6de0a28c9a

From what I can tell, the intended way to run a changelog update now is to use the `CommandScope` object instead. At least that's what they changed the deprecated update functions to do now. If you look into the change of the `public void update(Contexts contexts, LabelExpression labelExpression, boolean checkLiquibaseTables) throws LiquibaseException` method they now use following code to apply changelog updates:

```
CommandScope updateCommand = new CommandScope(UpdateCommandStep.COMMAND_NAME);
updateCommand.addArgumentValue(DbUrlConnectionCommandStep.DATABASE_ARG, getDatabase());
updateCommand.addArgumentValue(UpdateCommandStep.CHANGELOG_FILE_ARG, changeLogFile);
updateCommand.addArgumentValue(UpdateCommandStep.CONTEXTS_ARG, contexts != null ? contexts.toString() : null);
updateCommand.addArgumentValue(UpdateCommandStep.LABEL_FILTER_ARG, labelExpression != null ? labelExpression.getOriginalString() : null);
updateCommand.addArgumentValue(UpdateCommandStep.CHANGE_EXEC_LISTENER_ARG, changeExecListener);
updateCommand.addArgumentValue(DatabaseChangelogCommandStep.CHANGELOG_PARAMETERS, changeLogParameters);
updateCommand.execute();
```

I tried the same with a simpler approach, which worked for me:

```
private static void update(Database database, String changeLogLocation) throws CommandExecutionException {
    CommandScope updateCommand = new CommandScope(UpdateCommandStep.COMMAND_NAME);
    updateCommand.addArgumentValue(DbUrlConnectionCommandStep.DATABASE_ARG, database);
    updateCommand.addArgumentValue(UpdateCommandStep.CHANGELOG_FILE_ARG, changeLogLocation);
    updateCommand.execute();
}
```

Regarding the `Writer` argument of the non-deprecated update methods, I think that in this case all update queries are redirected to the passed `Writer` instead, so that the caller can hook into the updating process. At least when you create a simple implementation of `Writer` and log all content passed to the `write` method to the console, you'll see all the update queries.

All this information is based on my experience as a user of the library. So please don't take these observations as official statements. :)

Comment: Inside SpringLiquibase class they still use deprecated versions of methods https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/44ad21c97c98918647efbec9d287b92adeaeae9c/liquibase-standard/src/main/java/liquibase/integration/spring/SpringLiquibase.java#L331C24-L331C24
Because of that we don't have a working example of code migration.
Copy-paste of internals of deprecated update method doesn't look like a good idea for me